# Use Pyspark to linear interpolate

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, interpolation

I have a data frame below

```
data = [("A", "2022-01-01", 10.0),
    ("A", "2022-01-02", None),
    ("A", "2022-01-03", None),
    ("A", "2022-01-04", 40.0),
    ("B", "2022-01-01", 30.0),
    ("B", "2022-01-02", None),
    ("B", "2022-01-03", 60.0)]
```

columns = ["group", "date", "value"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

I'd like to group by column "group" and then linear interpolate the value by date.
How can I do it in Pyspark 2.4?
Thank you for any replies in advance.

I tried to calculate it by (next_value - prev_value)/(next_date - prev_date)*(next_date - curr_date). But I couldn't find a function to get the nearest available value. I found spark function lag and lead. But it's not what I need.

I tried this code to calculate the previous not-null value and next not-null value. But it's not working when there are 2 continuous null values.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lit
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType


data = [("A", "2022-01-01", 10.0),
        ("A", "2022-01-02", None),
        ("A", "2022-01-03", None),
        ("A", "2022-01-04", 40.0),
        ("B", "2022-01-01", 30.0),
        ("B", "2022-01-02", None),
        ("B", "2022-01-03", 60.0)]
columns = ["group", "date", "value"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df = df.withColumn("date", df["date"].cast("date"))

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("date")

df = df.withColumn("prev_value", sf.lag(df["value"]).over(window_spec))
df = df.withColumn("next_value", sf.lead(df["value"]).over(window_spec))

df= (
    df
    .withColumn("prev_date", sf.lag(df["value"].isNotNull()).over(window_spec))
    .withColumn("next_date", sf.lead(df["value"].isNotNull()).over(window_spec))
)
```

I hope to get a result below.

```
+-----+----------+-----+----------+----------+----------+---------- 
+
|group|      date|value|prev_value|next_value| prev_date| next_date|
+-----+----------+-----+----------+----------+----------+---------- 
+
|    B|2022-01-01| 30.0|      null|      60.0|      null|2022-01-03|
|    B|2022-01-02| null|      30.0|      60.0|2022-01-01|2022-01-03|
|    B|2022-01-03| 60.0|      30.0|      null|2022-01-01|      null|
|    A|2022-01-01| 10.0|      null|      40.0|      null|2022-01-04|
|    A|2022-01-02| null|      10.0|      40.0|2022-01-01|2022-01-04|
|    A|2022-01-03| null|      10.0|      40.0|2022-01-01|2022-01-04|
|    A|2022-01-04| 40.0|      10.0|      null|2022-01-01|      null|
+-----+----------+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Or are there other ways to linear interpolate the value in Pyspark 2.4?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula No, I'm not

Comment: Can you include what you have tried so far from your end? Include the output sample so that we can verify the output

Comment: Hi. I added my code. @Doof

Comment: The way you have done it, seems to be very good way for implementing this

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a good linear interpolation algorithm in Spark SQL might be difficult.

If the number of rows for a single group is not too large (probably just a few 10000 rows) these rows can be collected into an array (using `groupBy` with `collect_list` as aggregation function) and then an UDF can do the numeric magic using your favorite library, for example [numpy.interp](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html#numpy-interp).

**Define the UDF**

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

def interpolate(xy):
    import numpy as np
    a=np.array(xy, dtype=np.float64)
    a=a[a[:, 0].argsort()]
    vals=a[~np.isnan(a[:,1])]
    x=a[:,0]
    xp=vals[:,0]
    fp=vals[:,1]
    res = np.interp(x=x, xp=xp, fp=fp)
    return np.column_stack((x, res)).tolist()

interpolate_udf = F.udf(interpolate, T.ArrayType(T.ArrayType(T.FloatType())))
```

**Call the UDF**

```python
df.withColumn('date_ts', F.unix_timestamp('date')) \
  .withColumn('xy', F.array('date_ts', 'value')) \
  .groupBy('group').agg(F.collect_list('xy').alias('xy')) \
  .withColumn('result', interpolate_udf('xy') ) \
  .withColumn('xy', F.explode('result'))\
  .withColumn('date', F.from_unixtime(F.col('xy')[0]).cast('date')) \
  .withColumn('value', F.col('xy')[1]) \
  .drop('xy', 'result') \
  .show()
```

Result:

```
+-----+----------+-----+
|group|date      |value|
+-----+----------+-----+
|A    |2022-01-01|10.0 |
|A    |2022-01-02|20.0 |
|A    |2022-01-03|30.0 |
|A    |2022-01-04|40.0 |
|B    |2022-01-01|30.0 |
|B    |2022-01-02|45.0 |
|B    |2022-01-03|60.0 |
+-----+----------+-----+
```